# What's the reasoning behind the Uncaught Third Strike Rule?

Tags: rules, baseball

In MLB, if a Catcher drops or misses the third pitched strike, the batter becomes a runner and can attempt to reach first base before tagged out or forced out at first.

> 6.09 The batter becomes a runner when -- (a) He hits a fair ball; (b) The third strike called by the umpire is not caught, providing (1)
>   first base is unoccupied, or (2) first base is occupied with two out;
>   -- [Official MLB Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/official_info/official_rules/batter_6.jsp)

What is the reasoning behind this rule? Why does it only happen if first base is unoccupied, and what's with that crazy extra exception of two outs?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The exception about first base being unoccupied is to prevent a catcher from intentionally dropping a third strike and then getting a double-play.  If there are two outs, that prevention isn't necessary.

As for the reasoning behind the rule itself, I can't find a definitive resource, but speculation is that an out needs a successful defensive player and an unsuccessful offensive player to occur.

Comment: Ah, of course! Hadn't thought the first-base occupation through. Your speculation sounds right, too, and I noticed a similar guess on the wikipedia article.

Comment: So why can't the pitcher who threw the strike be considered the "successful defensive player"?

Comment: @JoelFan: Maybe it should be "successful defensive play" and "unsuccessful offensive play" instead of player.

Comment: @JoelFan Rule 6.05(b) states a batter is out when "A third strike is legally caught by the catcher;" so it appears that on third strike the catch is a requirement.

Comment: Also there is a general rule that in cases of "indirect outs" (i.e. outs due to penalties) the "closest defensive player" gets credit for an out. Clearly the catcher is closer to the batter than the pitcher is.

Comment: @JoelFan And indeed the catcher gets credited with a putout for a strikeout.  (Easy way to tell this: look at any regular full time catcher in baseball-reference.com.  He'll probably have 600-1000 putouts per season.  I'm not sure how often you get a player thrown out at home, but I'm not thinking it's 5 times per game.)

Comment: @JoelFan Thats interesting.  I agree with the `5 times a game part`, but coupled with strikeouts, the total seems like it would to low.  Maybe not. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it exists is the third strike has to be caught when its a foul tip so it has to be caught when its not a foul tip too.

Also the Catcher gets the PO on a strikeout so he is duty bound to actually catch it.

Answer (score -4):

The only problem I have with this rule is the ball hitting the ground or plate before it gets to the catcher.  Whether they call it a "dropped" third strike or an "uncaught" third strike, it hasn't gotten to the catcher yet.....if he/she catches it when it gets there, it should be an out....similar to a caught foul tip.  I see no merit in a batter swinging at a ball bouncing in the dirt being rewarded in all instances.
Steve B.